# Count based on another count - MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have the following [Set of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWVvI.png) and I want to get all the services, age ranges and genders and next to each three of them the count of recipients corresponding to them.
So far I came up with the statement below, and it works.

```
select s.service_name,s.service_id,g.gender_id,ag.age_range_id,count(r.recipient_id) Temp
from tbl_services s inner join tbl_gender g
                    inner join tbl_age_range ag
                    left join tbl_recipient_services rs on rs.service_id=s.service_id
                    left join tbl_recipient r on r.gender_id=g.gender_id and rs.recipient_id=r.recipient_id 
                                              and (year(sysdate())-year(r.recipient_birth_date) >=  min_age and year(sysdate())-year(r.recipient_birth_date) <=  max_age)
group by s.service_id,g.gander_id,ag.age_range_id
```

But I need to only count the recipients who have 2 or more services in the `tbl_recipient_services` and I'm stuck again.

Anyone has an idea to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your query would be clearer with `cross join`s:

```
select s.service_name, s.service_id, g.gender_id, ag.age_range_id,
       count(r.recipient_id) as all_recipients
from tbl_services s cross join
     tbl_gender g cross join
     tbl_age_range ag left join
     tbl_recipient_services rs
     on rs.service_id = s.service_id left join
     tbl_recipient r
     on r.gender_id = g.gender_id and
        rs.recipient_id = r.recipient_id and
        year(sysdate()) - year(r.recipient_birth_date) >=  min_age and
        year(sysdate()) - year(r.recipient_birth_date) <=  max_age)
group by s.service_id, g.gender_id, ag.age_range_id;
```

This returns all combinations of service/gender/age even if there are no matches.

Let's add another column.  To do so, we'll use a subquery to count the number of services per recipient and then include that in the count:

```
select s.service_name, s.service_id, g.gender_id, ag.age_range_id,
       count(r.recipient_id) as num_recipients,
       sum(rs2.num_services >= 2) as num_recipients_2plus 
from tbl_services s cross join
     tbl_gender g cross join
     tbl_age_range ag left join
     tbl_recipient_services rs
     on rs.service_id = s.service_id left join
     tbl_recipient r
     on r.gender_id = g.gender_id and
        rs.recipient_id = r.recipient_id and
        year(sysdate()) - year(r.recipient_birth_date) >=  min_age and
        year(sysdate()) - year(r.recipient_birth_date) <=  max_age) left join
    (select rs2.recipient_id, count(*) as num_services
     from tbl_recipient_services rs2
     group by rs2.recipient_id
    ) rs2
    on rs2.recipient_id = r.recipient_id
group by s.service_id, g.gender_id, ag.age_range_id;
```

If you don't want the additional column, you can change the `left join`s to inner joins and remove the `count(r.recipient_id)`.